# Implement a UIScrollView with different sections (i.e. Yahoo! Weather app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to figure out an optimal way to implement a UIScrollView similar to that of the Yahoo! Weather app.
As per image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj1xG.png) there's one section for 'Precipitation', one for 'Details', etc. 
Each of these sections is also movable up and down. It would also be ideal to be able to have a dynamic height (according to the length of the content that goes into one section) without the following section to overlap/be too far down, and to have the possibility to exclude and now show one or more section if certain conditions are not met.

Being a total amateur in Xcode and Objective-C programming, my approach would be just going with a single UIView and put elements in it, hiding/showing them when needed, simulating the division of the different sections with a UIImage with a background, and defining each element's position programmatically. I'm sure there's a better way to this painfully long and limited approach.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Create UIView and add in UIScrollview

Comment: I know how to create a scrollable view, but my question is how to implement the different sections?

Comment: better you can use UITableview with Custom UITableviewCell instead of UIScrollview

Comment: you have to set scrollview contentsize accrording to view height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should give UITableView a try.

[UITableView inherits from UIScrollView : UIView : UIResponder : NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you set the `tableView.pagingEnabled = YES;` you would get the desired effect.

Ray Wenderlich has an example [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/55384/ios-7-best-practices-part-1). Although the tutorial is on something else it starts by creating a paging enabled table view.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Better to use **Custom UITableView** with **custom cell** as uitableview has a method like -

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath     toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
  //Even if the method is empty you should be seeing both rearrangement icon and animation.
}
```

So you could easily have that sorting effects of Yahoo Weather app along with scroll up/down effect.